# I have used Database Reference then why i am getting all user data into recyclerview i only want only one user data into recycler view?

Tags: android, json, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

[Below is my current recyler view screenshot...i am getting staydetails all 8 nodes data its ok when i search single user but it also add into list of another user child node staydetails data that i dont want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppSDR.jpg)

My Firebase DataBase Structure is as per below:

[image: My Firebase DataBase Structure]

I want only single user "staydetails". Instead of that in my recycler Adapter i am getting all user data.

When I am adding multiple user and their room stay details while searching for one user it gives me all user staydetails data into adapter.
Here is my MainActivity  recycler view with adapter and database refrence. Thank you in Advance

```
    final String userformno = mobileorformnosearch.getText().toString().trim();
    globalmobileno = userformno;
    if (userformno.trim().length() == 10) {
        list.clear();
        PassDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Passanger");
        PassDataRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(userformno)) {
                        // run some code

                        //MobileNoDataWise
                        UserDataRegistration user = dataSnapshot.child(userformno).getValue(UserDataRegistration.class);

                        YatriName.setText(user.getUsername());
                        YatriAge.setText(user.getAge());
                        YatriCity.setText(user.getCity());
                        Yatriphonenumber.setText(user.getMobileno());
                        YatriformNo.setText(user.getFormno());
                        YatriCoachNo.setText(user.getCoachno());
                        YatriSeatNo.setText(user.getSeatno());
                        YatriBearth.setText(user.getBearth());
                        YatriBusno22.setText(user.getBustwono());
                        YatriBusSeatNo22.setText(user.getBustwoseatno());
                        YatriBusno32.setText(user.getBusthreeno());
                        YatriBusSeatNo32.setText(user.getBusthreeseatno());
                        YatriPhotoUri.setText(user.getProfilephoto());
                        YatriGender.setText(user.getGender());
                        YatriMBusno.setText(user.getMbusno());
                        YatriMBusSeatno.setText(user.getMseatno());
                        // String url ="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/uttammangal-ad8b8.appspot.com/o/profilepic%2F223.jpg?alt=media&token=703bcc8f-c2c3-4beb-bffc-40e52daa572d";// user.getProfilephoto();
                        String Url = user.getProfilephoto();
                        if (Url != null) {

                            Picasso
                                    .get()
                                    .load(Url)
                                    .resize(200, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel)
                                    .centerCrop()
                                    .into(YatriImageView);
                            // Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Url).into(YatriImageView);
                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO Image Found!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                        RecycleDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Passanger");
                        list.clear();
                       Query  qry = RecycleDataRef.child(userformno).child("StayDetails");
                        qry.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
                                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2 : dataSnapshot1.getChildren()) {
                                    //UserDataRegistration user = dataSnapshot.child(userformno).getValue(UserDataRegistration.class);

                                        UserDataRetrieve u = dataSnapshot2.getValue(UserDataRetrieve.class);
                                        //UserDataRetrieve u = dataSnapshot1.getValue(UserDataRetrieve.class);

                                        list.add(u);

                                }

                                adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);

                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });


                    } else {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Record Found!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                        break;
                    }

                }//ForloopClosing
                return;
            } //Main DataSnapshot Profile Data closing


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Valid MobileNo!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        }); //addvaluelistner main profile Data Closing

        //} //Query node equals closing


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter 10 Digit MobileNo!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

} //OnClick Closing
```

Comment: Provide screenshot of your current RecyclerView. Not clear about what do you want to show and what you get?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I am having current two user into database. I want only one user user data into recycler view as when searching user i am getting data of one user when it finishes adaper gor data of another user that i dont want to add into same list of current user which i have search

Comment: From where do you get user info? I think each passenger have details with basic info under UserId, right?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman yes variable "userformno" is  child node of "Passenger" i want only single userformno data of "staydetails" node instead of that I am getting all userformno who containing "staydetails" in recycler adapter list /I have added 10 user i get staydetails data into recycler view is 8*10= 80 cards that i dont want... i only want 8 as only 8 data into staydetails

Comment: I got the solution i missed break into forloop thank you for response

Comment: That means you print same user info 10 times not other user info, right? But your approach is not optimal, please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of loop through all users you can simply get the user data that you want through search like below:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Passanger").child(userformno).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                UserDataRegistration user = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserDataRegistration.class);

                ...

                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("StayDetails")) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2 : dataSnapshot.child("StayDetails").getChildren()) {
                        UserDataRetrieve u = dataSnapshot2.getValue(UserDataRetrieve.class);
                        //UserDataRetrieve u = dataSnapshot1.getValue(UserDataRetrieve.class);
                        list.add(u);
                    }

                   ...

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Record Found!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
);
```

Hope this will give you the exact data that you want.

Comment: Thank you so much it helps!! instead of for loops this works better